# Is it safe to convert function parameter `const char*` to `std::string_view`?

Tags: c++, c++17, null-terminated, string-view

The title almost says it all.

```
void f(const char*)
```

*to*

```
void f(std::string_view)
```

Is it safe? if not, what are the pitfalls?

`std::string_view` semantics dictate that the array isn't necessarily null terminated, which can be a real issue inside `f` since that has be taken into account (eg. if the raw pointer is passed onto a function expecting null termination inside of `f`).

Comment: Nothing is "safe" in C++. You have to fully understand the implications of each change. Only you can figure out if this is "safe" in your specific program. Maybe it is, maybe it isn't, only you have the access to the full program, and only you can figure it out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The question is within the context of commonly accepted semantics.

Comment: The problem is that if you ask two C++ developers whether "X" is "commonly accepted", you will get three different answers.

Comment: And you'll get them in the comments section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it safe?

Yes, it is safe, in so far as it is correct.  If someone gives you garbage you'll still have garbage.

> what are the pitfalls?

As you've said, `std::string_view` need not be null terminated.  If you are going to need a null terminated c-string somewhere further along the call chain then you can't use this because you can't guarantee you'll have one.

Comment: Depending on how big the string is expected to be you might just want to have `void f(std::string)`.  copying linear data (array like) is really quick so you might even notice the copy depending on the use case.

Comment: It's not just a copy, it's also [probably] a dynamic allocation and some indirection. That adds up

Comment: There is no such guarantee about the `const char*` either. In fact, the problem is not further down the call chain, it's been "moved" to _right here_, because constructing a `string_view` from a `const char*` without a length argument requires that the `const char*` point to a terminated buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe?

Not in general.

> if not, what are the pitfalls?

This :

> std::string_view semantics dictate that the array isn't necessarily null terminated, which can be a real issue inside f since that has be taken into account (eg. if the raw pointer is passed onto a function expecting null termination inside of f).

As long as the implementation of the function does not rely on null termination, the change is safe.

But if the implementation does rely on null termination, then the change would be unsafe until that implementation is changed.

Assuming that the implementation of the function does not rely on null termination would be unsafe.

Comment: That's not really true; there is _already_ a precondition of `f` that the argument be null-terminated, because we weren't provided a length argument. And as for whether that changes the "safety", well there is as just much of a guarantee that the original `const char*` pointee were null terminated. The actual problem is that if it _weren't_, the conversion to `string_view` probably has UB, and so if `f` did not previously rely on the input being terminated, _it does now_. So that's kind of the opposite of what you're saying ;)

Comment: `there is already a precondition of f that the argument be null-terminated` That is exactly what makes the change unsafe: It removes that precondition. Which is a problem if the implementation of the function relies on that precondition. `if it weren't, the conversion to string_view probably has UB` It is perfectly well defined to construct a non-null-terminated `std::string_view`. `If f did not previously rely on the input being terminated, it does now.` The API most definitely does not guarantee the input to be null terminated after the change.

Comment: It doesn't remove that precondition. Preconditions for a function are not limited to the preconditions of the types of its arguments. It is deducible that a precondition of `f` _must_ have been that its argument was a pointer to a _null-terminated_ buffer (even though `const char*` itself does not require this). There is nothing about this code change that inherently alters that precondition.

Comment: _"It is perfectly well defined to construct a non-null-terminated std::string_view."_ Not from a `const char*` (without a size argument) it isn't. Think about how that would work. Then consult http://eel.is/c++draft/string.view.cons#2 ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings That's a technicality. Precondition "the `std::string_view` must refer to a null terminated string" is a silly pre-condition that should never exist.

Comment: How could it _not_ exist? Where would the view end.... That information is missing.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings `Not from a const char* (without a size argument) it isn't.` But from a `const char*` **with** a size argument it is. Think about how that would work.

Comment: But that's not the situation we're talking about! Who's providing that size argument? There is no size in any of the OP's given examples. The information doesn't exist, _except_ by calculating it from the _null-terminated_ input.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings `Where would the view end...` `std::string_view` ends at `sv.data() + sv.size()`. There is absolutely no guarantee that `sv.back()` is the null terminator, and there is no guarantee that accessing `sv[sv.size()]` doesn't have undefined behaviour. And as a consequence, thre is no guarntee that passing `sv.data()` into a function that requires null terminated string, wouldn't have undefined behaviour either.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings `But that's not the situation we're talking about!` I don't know what situation you are talking about, but I am talking about the question of whether replacing `const char*` argument with `std::string_view` is safe. `Who's providing that size argument?` Whoever creates the string view that is passed into the function.